# react-native-maps: animateToRegion does not work with region or initialRegion?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

In short: Why animateToRegion does not work with region or initialRegion?

I have tested this behaviour and noticed that animateToRegion also does not work while it is used in useEffect() => {}, []);
But if I add a simple button with function to animateToRegion then animateToRegion with region or initialRegion will work. And it also works if I animateToRegion onPress/onLongPress on MapView.

The following code is pretty much the usage of MapView. fitToMarker() basically takes location from user or from default location and then passes them to animateToRegionHolder().

```
const mapRef = React.useRef<MapView | null>(null);
  
const animateToRegionHolder = (lat: number, lng: number) => {
    if (mapRef.current) {
      mapRef.current.animateToRegion(
        {
          latitude: lat,
          longitude: lng,
          latitudeDelta: 0.2,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        },
        1000,
      );
    }
  };

<MapView
    ref={mapRef}
    onMapReady={fitToMarker}
    style={[S.MapsStyles.mapView, defineMapContainerStyle()]}
        /**
         * This for some reason affects that fitToMarker will not work
         * But removing this will affect slight animation (which is not desired) on initial render
         * initialRegion={O.region}
         */
        >
<MapView>
```

"expo": "^43.0.0",
"react-native-maps": "0.28.0",

**SOLUTION PRESENTED FOR READERS**
The problem occurred because of using `onMapReady` with `initialRegion`. It was solved by using `onRegionChangeComplete` conditionally:
When dragging of map is needed **it is not used**, but when initial `animateToRegion` is needed **it is used**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `useRef` instead. Here is a working example:

```
const mapRef = React.useRef<MapView >(null);
```

```
<MapView
  ref={mapRef}
  initialRegion={initialRegion}
  onRegionChangeComplete={handleRegionChange}
/>
```

```
mapRef.current?.animateToRegion({
  latitude: selectedCoordinates.lat,
  longitude: selectedCoordinates.lng,
  longitudeDelta: 0.004,
  latitudeDelta: 0,
});
```

Comment: I have tried both useRef and useState and lastly I seemly used  useState. But changing those did not help for this problem. But thank you for the answer.

Comment: I'm sure you need to use useRef. Maybe you can add a git repo or live demo so people can easily debug the issue. The above worked for me.

Comment: Hey I noticed you used method: "onRegionChangeComplete". Seemly that method works perfectly with little adjustments so my problem somehow exists while using "onMapReady" with "initialRegion". And I changed to use useRef. So I found solution through your answer and will mark it as correct, but I would like to ask is "onRegionChangeComplete" preferred method or would you suggest some else?

Comment: This worked. Changing it from `createRef` to `useRef` finally fixed it. Thanks.